# Generic object return type is result of method chaining

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to do the following:

```js
var result = loader
    .add<number>(1)
    .add<string>("hello")
    .add<boolean>(true)
    .run();
```

I would like to construct this theoretical `loader` object in such a way to have the TYPE of result be `[number, string, boolean]` without needing to manually declare it as such. Is there a way to do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: TypeScript 4.0 will feature [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), which will allow more flexible built-in tuple manipulation. `Push<T, V>` will be simply implemented as `[...T, V]`.   Therefore the entire implementation turns into the following relatively straightforward bit of code:

```
type Loader<T extends any[]> = {
    add<V>(x: V): Loader<[...T, V]>;
    run(): T
}
declare const loader: Loader<[]>;

var result = loader.add(1).add("hello").add(true).run(); //[number, string, boolean]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-pr-39094-7#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYQE4B4AqUIA9gQB2SAzlAoSANoC6AfFALxQDeAsAFBTflJLoA1OgApcALigCAlBPjI06KgDoVmADST6Abk48oqAK6FhMqJk4BfTigDGAGwSpoNuIRLAodxClSzvC2jodDk4AN0d9CBIDOw9mL3lUJWQkYQBGKWS+YQAiAAsIOy8czJThYEMITMNjKS0oAHoGqkIDAFsAIzQNd1QAS0IAcw0OuDg7CAoaKCA)

---

FOR TS before v4.0:

There is unfortunately no supported way in TypeScript to represent the type operation of appending a type onto the end of a tuple.  I'll call this operation `Push<T, V>` where `T` is a tuple and `V` is any value type.  There *is* a way to represent *prepending* a value onto the *beginning* of a tuple, which I'll call `Cons<V, T>`.  That's because in TypeScript 3.0, a feature was introduced to [treat tuples as the types of function parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).   We can also get `Tail<T>`, which pulls the first element (the head) off a tuple and returns the rest:

```
type Cons<H, T extends any[]> = 
  ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
type Tail<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...x: T) => void) extends ((h: infer A, ...t: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

Given `Cons` and `Tail`, the natural representation of `Push` would be this [recursive thing that doesn't work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980):

```
type BadPush<T extends any[], V> = 
  T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], BadPush<Tail<T>, V>>; // error, circular
```

The idea there is that `Push<[], V>` should just be `[V]` (appending to an empty tuple is easy), and `Push<[H, ...T], V>` is `Cons<H, Push<T, V>>` (you hold onto the first element `H` and just push `V` onto the tail `T`... then prepend `H` back onto the result).

While possible to trick the compiler into allowing such recursive types, [it is not recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254).  What I usually do instead is pick some maximum reasonable length of tuple I want to support modifying (say 9 or 10) and then unroll the circular definition:

```
type Push<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push1<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push1<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push2<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push2<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push3<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push3<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push4<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push4<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push5<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push5<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push6<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push6<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push7<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push7<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push8<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push8<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], Push9<Tail<T>, V>>
type Push9<T extends any[], V> = T['length'] extends 0 ? [V] : Cons<T[0], PushX<Tail<T>, V>>
type PushX<T extends any[], V> = Array<T[number] | V>; // give up
```

Each line except `PushX` looks just like the recursive definition, and we intentionally cut things off at `PushX` by giving up and just forgetting about the order of elements (`PushX<[1,2,3],4>` is `Array<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>`).

Now we can do this:

```
type Test = Push<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 9> // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

Armed with `Push`, let's give a type to `loader` (leaving the implementation up to you):

```
type Loader<T extends any[]> = {
  add<V>(x: V): Loader<Push<T, V>>;
  run(): T
}
declare const loader: Loader<[]>;
```

And let's try it:

```
var result = loader.add(1).add("hello").add(true).run(); //[number, string, boolean]
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

---

### UPDATE

The above only works with `--strictFunctionTypes` enabled.  If you must do without that compiler flag, you could use the following definition of `Push` instead:

```
type PushTuple = [[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
type Push<
    T extends any[],
    V,
    L = PushTuple[T['length']],
    P = { [K in keyof L]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : V }
    > = P extends any[] ? P : never;
```

It's more terse for small supported tuple sizes, which is nice, but the repetition is quadratic in the number of supported tuples (O(n<sup>2</sup>) growth) instead of linear (O(n) growth), which is less nice.  Anyway it works by using [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) which were introduced in TS3.1.

It's up to you.

Good luck again!

Comment: This is an awesome solution. I'm totally fine with picking a reasonable maximum. However, I tried using your example exactly as you provided, and the type inferred from result is `[number, ...undefined[]]`. Is it possible that your example isn't quite correct? I'm using typescript  3.1.6

Comment: Turn on `--strict` for your own sake (or at least `--strictFunctionTypes` which seems to be the cause here) if you can.  I'm sure there's some change I could make to have `Push` work without it, but `--strict` is so useful that I try to spend as little time as possible with it off.

Comment: updated with version of `Push` that works without `--strict`