# Merge generic tuples

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following function:

```
function merge<T extends any[], U>(current: T, toAdd: U) {
    current.push(toAdd);
    return current;
} 

const x = merge<[string, number], string>(["1", 2], "3");
```

The type of `x` is incorrectly set to `[string, number]` but I would like to specifically signal that the return type is a merge between the two generic types.

How can I express the return type?

Comment: Adding at the beginning is possible, adding at the end is also possible but not really recommended, as it is done with a recursive type alias and those kill compiler performance.

Comment: Beginning:  http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Cons%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20Parameters%3C(u%3A%20U%2C%20...a%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%3E%0D%0Afunction%20merge%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20U%3E(current%3A%20T%2C%20toAdd%3A%20U)%3A%20Cons%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20current.splice(0%2C0%2CtoAdd)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20current%20as%20any%20as%20Cons%3CT%2C%20U%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%20merge%3C%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D%2C%20string%3E(%5B%221%22%2C%202%5D%2C%20%223%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%2F%20%5Bstring%2C%20string%2C%20number%5D

Comment: What's the expected return type? `[string, number, string]`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir could you please expand on the performance issue? What would influence the performance? The size of the array? The depth?

Comment: @AndreiV Not 100% sure, it will behave badly with a lot of items for sure, but even a smaller arrays with many invocations might cause problems ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Okay. Thanks! This might be a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I'm trying to build a fluent API where a specific generic function will be called multiple times (with possibly different types) and would merge all these types into an array. Is there a better way of "propagating" types between recursive calls?

Comment: @AndreiV really depends what you are trying to do, if you post a full example I will have a look (also someone else might have ideas, jcalz  can confirm or contradict me on the tuple pushing thing, 95% sure I am right about it :) )

Comment: Yeah, it's [ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55067683/2887218).  Not impossible, though.  (The update at the bottom of the answer uses mapped tuples to avoid a recursive-like answer, but it's still a hack)

Comment: @jcalz after losing a couple of hours looking around and testing, I didn't think it was possible in any other "hack free" way...